# How execute a function after a delay

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, setinterval

I need to execute a function in a future so I do this:

```
   setTimeout(function(){ console.log("hi");}, 3000));
```

The problem is that I want print ONLY AFTER that 3000 ms are passed. Anyone can help me?

Comment: @JaromandaX OP is using `setTimeout`

Comment: @ OP, what's the problem with your code?

Comment: @JaromandaX http://prntscr.com/gb3us5

Comment: @JoeB, is this the code you're trying to run? https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout

Comment: @JaromandaX you need to refresh the page.

Comment: Without a description of what is wrong? Well, remove the extra `)` at the front of the code.

Comment: Close this as a simple typo and move on.

Answer (score 9):

The extra ")" is causing an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ")".
By removing it the code will output your text after 3 seconds.

```js
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Your text!");}, 3000);
```

Comment: I do not know why every question here gets downvoted, your quiestion seems clear to me!

Comment: We got working answers and not one is marked

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you have an extra bracket `)` after `3000`

```js
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("hi");}, 3000);
```

Comment: `)` is not a comma - you made my brain hurt dude!!

Comment: @JaromandaX It's monday dude.. my bad. Fixed.

Comment: all good - after the weirdness of seeing setInterval where everyone else saw setTimeout, this answer was just doing my head in :p

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra ")". This is working:

```
 setTimeout(function(){ 
     console.log("hi");
     }, 3000);
```